# Multiple Activities / Fragments and the Model View Presenter pattern

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, design-patterns, mvp

Firstly, I know that with Model View Presenter there are different implementations, and in my mind as long as you have the layers of abstraction clearly defined and doing their appointed roles then how you implement this pattern is open to interpretation.  I have been implementing this pattern in quite a few apps where there was just one `Activity`.  I've now started a new project that has multiple Activities and attached `Fragments`, including nested fragments (`ViewPager`).

I'm now trying to translate the MVP to this project and I've hit a concept wall and would like some guidance and insights.

So far I've created the above structure and started to do a 1 : 1 relationship with View & Presenter (regardless of `Activity` or `Fragment`).  I feel that this is OK, however if for example I sent a request to do something from an `Activity` View to its Presenter, which returns a result to the `Activity` View how would I go about propagating the result i.e. update all the other Activities/Fragments that are currently not in a `Paused()` or `Stop()` state.  I feel like in this case there should be a central Presenter that updates all necessary Activity and Fragment Views, but I'm not sure how to go about doing this.

Currently when each `Activity` and `Fragment` is created it creates a new instance of a Presenter class, passing in itself as a reference (the Activities and Fragments implement their own interfaces), which the presenter stores as a `WeakReference` and can invoke the relevant interface methods when returning a result.

According to the docs whenever `Fragments` want to communicate with one another and the attached `Activity` you should use a callback interface.   With this in mind should I have one callback interface that the Activity implements and the `Fragments` callback to whenever they request something, so in essence only the Activity would have a Presenter and Model layer that the Fragments have to callback to in order to make various requests?

Sorry if this sounds a bit muddled, hopefully this is clear enough to understand what I want to achieve, and if I’m thinking along the right lines... or totally off the mark!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is okay to have a presenter inside activity. Basically activity is like a controller, it should know about the presenter.

It would be wrong to put a presenter inside a fragment if activity or other fragment needs it too. You can put a presenter inside a fragment only if this presenter is designed specifically for fragment.

> which the presenter stores as a WeakReference and can invoke the relevant interface methods when returning a result

Why do you need a `WeakReference` here? If you have 1:1 relationship then I assume your presenter does not have it's own lifecycle, meaning that it's lifecycle depends on either activity or fragment. There is no risk of having memory leaks because it's not a singleton, right? It should be safe to have a strong reference.

I'm not sure if I answered your question because it looks a bit broad to me. My point is that, fragments are just separated "parts" of activity and you should treat them as parts. If presenter belongs to this part only, then it should be inside. Otherwise it should be in activity. You are right about using an `interface` to access activity, this is a well-known design approach which Google uses in their examples.

Comment: Thanks for your comments and thoughts. I think I'll just use the Presenter with the Activity, and let that handle updating the fragments.  Memory leaks with a Singleton? This would only happen if the Singleton had a reference to an Activity or Fragment (basically something with a lifecycle that may come and go)? If so, I do use a singleton for something else, but it holds no references.  I use `WeakReferences` with Activities and Fragments (anything with lifecycle callbacks) as I don't have to `null` Strong references on configuration changes, and the `WeakReference` allows GC

Comment: If your presenter is not a singleton then you shouldn't have any issue with configuration changes because the presenter itself will be recreated too. You might need a `WeakReference` if you use a retained fragment though. Anyway, it seems you clearly understand how weak references work, so I don't need to explain this.. Thank you.

Comment: No the presenter is not a singleton, After the presenter is created I store a reference of it in a `HashMap<String, Object>` within headless retained fragment, and retrieve its reference back on configuration changes with the Activity. ... Just when I think I understand something in Java it seems to always throw me a curve ball! Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, no interface anymore. You either use `RxJava Observables` to update all the views as described [here](https://github.com/ribot/android-guidelines/blob/master/architecture_guidelines/android_architecture.md) or some kind of `Bus`([Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/)-deprecated or [EventBus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/)). And you will like it because they make interacting too easy.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have had a look at these briefly - and do look quite feasible and interesting.  I was looking for a pattern solution or concept rather than 'this library takes the complexity away'.  I'm not against using this, or any other libraries that solve problems, far from it, but I think its important for me to grasp a good understanding before jump straight into using these other libraries that handle a lot of the complexities for you.

Comment: İ would call it Reactive programming approach, not library. And i don't see other way to escape Rx anymore in near future.

Comment: I will look at Reactive programming / RxJava for sure, for now, for me and this project communcating through the hosting activity isn't an issue. I'm not sure I share your belief that there isn't a way to 'escape' Reactive programming, however I respect your opinion.